# appropriate UML diagram to model Android app's Threads, network activity, Handlers, etc

Tags: android, concurrency, uml

I'm writing an Android app that, among other things:

- Spawns a thread that binds a network socket to port 42777 when {Activity}.onResume() executes, and dispatches incoming data to a Handler. Unless no WLAN adapter currently has a connection with a local (192.168.*, 10.*, 172.16-31.*) IP address... then, it displays an error message and does nothing further until a suitable WLAN connection comes into existence and ConnectivityManager notifies my listener.
- Spawns a thread that fetches Runnables from a LinkedBlockingQueue, and submits them to a single-threaded ExecutorService. At this point, the Runnables basically broadcast a datagram via UDP to 255.255.255.255.
- when {Activity}.onPause() executes, the socket on port 42777 gets closed & released, the LinkedBlockingQueue gets clear()'ed, and the ExecutorService (and the Thread that feeds it  Runnables) gets interrupted and killed. And the port bound to the socket hopefully gets released before the next time {Activity}.onResume() fires and tries to reopen the socket... otherwise, I'll have to tangle the rat's nest even more, and add logic to hammer away at the network stack until the port finally gets released.

What UML diagram(s) would be appropriate to document something like this so I can go into this with a fairly clear understanding of how the classes interact with each other? I've been using class diagrams for years, but documenting chains of events that indirectly spawn Threads spawning Threads in response to Handler events is (up to now) unexplored territory for me.

Answer (score 3):

You get by with a mix of sequence and state diagrams.

- Sequence diagrams can show how functionality is performed in certain scenarios. E.g. for your first example you have the `main` instance on the left which instantiates a `thread` (whatever it's meaningful name may be). This will first call the `bind`, listen to incoming data and dispatch data to a `Handler`. etc. You will create such SDs for different scenarios where you might think that a graphical representation adds value to the reader of the model. Eventually you get by with activity diagrams which explain behavior on a higher, abstract level.
- State diagrams are useful to communicate "if-this-then-that" states of your machine. So the `thread` enters a `Connect` state until it gets the port and then enters a `Listening` state which transfers to `Dispatch`, etc.

Note that the two diagrams are not redundant. The state machine could almost directly be transferred to code. There are also tools that can simulate a state machine, which is most helpful for complex machines. The sequence diagram just shows an example of how a scenario works. You eventually use it to do some kind of "static simulation". In most cases you need a set of different sequence diagram to transmit the idea.

As @Ister points out, you will need the appropriate class diagrams to show the static structure of your class model. This is essential and usually the "dew point" of a model. I had assumed that this is already present :-)

Comment: I would add to that that you still represent the structure using class diagram. That's why we build model from multiple diagrams - to represent different bits of logic. Some are about static part of system, other about dynamic (behavioural) aspect of it. You need to combine them together to have a full view of a system.

Comment: @Ister You are absolutely right. One of those self-evident things you forget to mention :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem statement mentions an **activity** that processes the content of a queue, that may be paused and resumed (seems to be special events).

The most appropriate diagram to document such kind of "chains of events that indirectly spawn threads spawning threads" would be the [**activity** diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html), which provides means to represent:

- complex control flows with sequence of actions, conditionals, events and signals;
  *[object flows](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html) that create a sequencing (i.e. one action gets objects such as `Runnable` or `Datagram` that is used for the next action);
- spawning and joining of [concurrent flows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409465.aspx#Concurrent) (i.e. your threads);
- partitioning to group sub-flows in a flexible and expressive manner.

This kind of diagram is however less good at showing the interactions between the object. These would be best represented by a sequence diagram.

Of course, this could be complemetned by a state diagram, as explained in other answers.  I think however that it would be overkill for the two identified states (processing and paused with transition from the one to the other) and would not give the detailed description of what happens at state transition, as you have described it in your bullets.

Answer (score 0):

I belive state diagram will be the best for modeling that. See what wikipedia has to say about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram_(UML)).

Comment: Could you elaborate ? How would you show "how the classes interact with each other" with a state diagram ?  How would you "document chains of events that indirectly spawn Threads spawning Threads" ?